# Android external Storage read only one line

Tags: android, file, save

I want to read just the third  line of a text-File in /sdcard/Android/data/com.example/Files/. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Tried anything before asking here?

Comment: Sugesstion - Read as usual, and keep a counter to do something with just the third line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LineIterator ip = IOUtils.lineIterator( new BufferedReader(FileReader("__.txt"))); for (int lineNumber = 0; it.hasNext(); lineNumber++) { String line = (String) ip.next(); if (lineNumber == 3) { return line; } }
```

Comment: I've tried this script but i can't input LineIterator :(